# Get value of specific css class from selected tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table with multiple rows which all are structured the same.

I can select the clicked row via jQuery, but now i want to get the value of a certain field with the css class "book" which lais within the row.

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.book_listing', function(){
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
        // That's the code I tried to get the val
        console.log($(this).find('.book').val());
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Stuff 1</th>
      <th>Stuff 2</th>
      <th>Stuff 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="book_listing">
      <td><button class="book">The value I want</button></td>
      <td>Other stuff</td>
      <td>and so on</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But I'm not the value of the button from the code above.

How can I access the value of the button from the selected tr?

Comment: use $(this).find('.book').text()

Comment: @AlexG Well, that works! But can you tell me why? Also add this as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @KhorneHoly the `val()` method is used to get teh value of input elements like `input`, `select` and `textarea`. Since you want the contents of a `td` you need to use `.text()` or `.html()` based on your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use

```
$(this).find('.book').text()
```

or you can use

```
$(this).find('.book').html()
```

If you use .text() then you will get text, if you use .html() you will get text with markup.
example

```
<button class="book">The value I <b>want</b></button>

.text() will return: The value I want
.html() will return: The value I <b>want</b>
```

.val() i used for inputs, selects and textarea. that's why its not working at yours code.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination!